# Ifstream is OK but Ofstream not working in Visual Studio (C++)(WIN11)

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

When I write a simple ofstream and ifstream instance ,ifstream is working but ofstream is not working. When I run this program ofstream is creating but I don't see output.txt in directory file.
I tried turning off COMODO Antivirus but the problem persists.
What is preventing me from seeing the output file?

here my First.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream output("output.txt");
    ifstream input("input.txt");
    if (output.is_open()) {
        cout << "ouput file is open" << endl;
        output << "hi";
    }
    else {
        cout << "output file is not open" << endl;
    }
    int number;
    if (input.is_open()) {
        cout << "input file is open" << endl;
        input >> number;
        cout << "Number:" << number << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "input file is not open" << endl;
    }
    input.close();
    output.close();
    return 0;
}
```

here my input.txt:

```
21
12
22
23
32
```

when I run this program:

```
ouput file is open
input file is open
Number:21
```

Comment: I can't speak for VS, but in XCode the issue is likely not looking in the correct location. It won't be next to your executable. Get to know your IDE's settings.

Comment: I tried your program in Visual Studio and it worked for me. I can only think that you are not looking in the right place.

Comment: I tried this: ofstream output("C:\\Users\\vasip\\Desktop\\First\\First\\output.txt"); But still output.txt is empty.

Comment: @ismailVasip Well the code is correct, what else your problem might be I can't say.

Comment: OK I solved . 
COMODO Antivirus output.txt is preventing the file from appearing. Open COMODO Antivirus, go to Unblock Applications section and find the .exe file of your program and unblock it.

Comment: @ismailVasip Glad you solved it, the alternative is to switch to a better AV product.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the issue was related to your Antivirus, but I'll write this anyways for others to read.

When dealing with IO its important to know what directory your executable will execute from. The working directory can be set in the project configuration. **Right Click the project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Working Directory**. [Configuration Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IG9d.png)

The working directory is also the directory where all your application created files will be generated. For instance the example code generate **output.txt** at the project working directory.

```
std::ofstream output("output.txt");
if (!output.is_open())
return -1;

std::cout << "file is open" << std::endl;
output << "Hello there!";
output.flush();
output.close();
```

[project directory screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2mGL.png)

Comment: `flush` is unnecessary as `close` will flush, and `close` is unnecessary because the destructor will close the file. Adding redundant code is not a good habit, quite the opposite.

Comment: I can buy that Close Flushes, but calling Close a redundancy and therefore unnecessary is something I want to challenge since you can reuse a ofstream multiple times. And therefore you should cleanup after yourself, to both clear up resources. But also to avoid corruption

Comment: Sure if you are going to reuse the stream then you must close, but that is not the case here. That destructors should be used to clean up resources is a fundamental C++ concept and the fstream classes do this for you. It's not wrong to manually close a stream when the destructor is about to do that for you anyway but it is redundant.

Comment: I don't see a benefit to calling out good practices just because the example is a toy program. My philosophy is that you should close as soon as you're done with the file instead of making the program hold on to it for no good reason. I just don't see much of a point in going after a 7 line snippet.